# egui: how to know if a window or an area has been moved to top?

Tags: rust, egui

I have an object, which implements egui App trait. When I run this object, a main egui window appears with several windows and areas inside it.

When updating this object, I want to know if some window/area is on top (within the object main egui window) in order to move another window/area associated with it to the top of this main window at the same time.

More precisely, I need to manage more than two windows or areas in the main egui window.
But two of these windows/areas (actually a window and an area) must always be viewed in successive z-order (the first always behind the second).
In particular, this should happen when focusing on one of them (or when moving or resizing the window).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking about. are you asking about z-order of elements in an egui window? Are you asking about z-order of multiple windows? Are you asking about focus? Are you asking about within one app, or multiple apps?

Comment: Ok! I tried to give more details.